# Let the client create his/her own custom MySQL query to get data from the database in vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net, vb.net-2010

I want a program that lets the user create his/her own query to retrieve data from the database. What is the best method to achieve such task? Any links or sample code would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for :

Create a form, name it formSample 
add a textbox, name it txbSample
add a datagridview, name it dgvSample
add a button, name it btnSample

txbSample will be used by the client to input queries
btnSample is where you would put the code.
dgvSample is the data, not really recommended but it's just used to show the data you have retrieved.

assuming you have connected to the database, the code on btnSample should look like

**NOTE:** not a complete code

```
Dim sql As String
sql = txbSample.text

Using cmd As New MySqlCommand
   Try
      'open the connection here
      cmd.Connection = con
      cmd.CommandText = sql
      Dim dt As New DataTable
      da = New MySqlDataAdapter(cmd)
      da.Fill(dt)
      'close the connection here
      dgvSample.DataSource = dt
   Catch ex As Exception
      MessageBox.Show("Error while fetching data.")
      'close the connection here
   End Try
End Using


dt is a datatable where the data are stored. You should do something to be able to use it:)
```